# Linear gradients possible with -webkit-border-image?

Tags: html, css, webkit, border, gradient

Is there a way I can get the styling of the second example down from:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

That has the CSS:

```
/* Gradient transparent - color - transparent */

hr.style-two {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}
```

on a div or p element? Or really any element that can hold content? I tried a bunch of variations of -webkit-border-image and the above code but wasn't able to make anything work.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

So I twiddled around the example on this site: http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder and got the following to achieve the effect I want:

```css
div {
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 0 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Granted, this is just for webkit, but I suspect the other -o-* and -moz-* would work as well.